# Self-hosted alternatives to Ghost CMS for blogging

Tags: cms, wordpress, self-hosted, blog

I was looking for a WordPress alternative for my blog and I've been using [Ghost CMS](https://ghost.org) for a while now. I really like the idea behind it and how it's built, however, I'm starting to dislike their approach to "solve" things. They usually recommend installing what the called "integrations, which most of the time are paid apps, and getting things to work is starting to be kind of a hustle.

I would like to know if you guys can recommend any good alternative to get my blog up and running. After some research, I haven't found anything on my own but it may be something out there that I'm not aware of.

The main features I'm looking for are:

- Self-hosted
- Multi-language (I write my content in two languages)
- SEO oriented